# Php, create new array on basis of value missing for key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "name" => "one",
        "date" => "2016-10-10",
        "data"=> 30
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "one",
        "date" => "2016-10-11",
        "data"=> 30
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "two",
        "date" => "2016-10-10",
        "data"=> 40
    )
);
```

Now I want to merge the difference of arrays, like if an array (name => one) has two dates (2016-10-10 and 2016-10-10) but array (name => two) has only one date (2016-10-10), I want to add 2016-10-11 with array (name => two).

```
array(
    "name" => "two",
    "date" => "2016-10-11",
    "data"=> 0
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: It difficult to express what really i want :)
in short actually i want to add array(
    "name" => "two",
    "date" => "2016-10-11",
    "data"=> 0
) this.

Comment: array "name" => "two", don't have the date 2016-10-11 like array "name"=>"one" have, i just want to add this.

Comment: You want to add the new array with a name of "two" to the original array?

Comment: Yes, but with the date "201-10-11" that is missing.

Comment: but the issue is how i can check which date is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a simpler way I haven't thought of, but I think it looks like the solution takes three steps.

1. Group your values by date

   ```
   foreach ($array as $row) {
       $dates[$row['date']][$row['name']] = $row['data'];
   }
   ```
2. Get a unique list of all the names

   ```
   $names = array_unique(array_column($array, 'name'));
   ```
3. Iterate the date groups and fill the missing values into your original array.

   ```
   foreach ($dates as $date => $date_names) {
       foreach ($names as $name) {
           if (!isset($date_names[$name])) {
               $array[] = ['name' => $name, 'date' => $date, 'data' => 0];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

(This should also work the same if you group by name and get a unique list of dates.)

Comment: That's Perfect. :) Thank you.